# Capture and Encode Webcam Video in Silverlight4/5 Not Possible?

Tags: webcam, silverlight-5.0

I have spent the last few days trying to find a way to encode and store video/audio from a webcam in Silverlight 4 or 5. Apart from one codeplex project that seems a little out of date and doesn't work, I can't see that there is a way to acheive this.

Is there a .Net (non flash) way of doing this. I am disappointed that Expression Encoder Pro doesn't offer this functionality in it's SDK.

Input from someone on the Silverlight project at Microsoft is needed.

regards
Barry

Comment: Have you looked at http://www.silverlight.net/learn/graphics/webcam-and-mic/webcams-%28silverlight-quickstart%29?